# Hello, do you know how to fix this problem? It seems not working

Tags: solidity

```
pragma solidity >= 0.7.0 < 0.9.0;

contract FinalExcercise {

uint a = 300;
uint b = 12;
uint f = 47;


function finalize () public view returns (uint) {
uint d = 23;

returns = d;

if (a <= a && b < f) {
   return = d(2) - b
   return = result; 
}
 }

  }
```

I tried in different ways but I got this mistake: ParserError: Expected primary expression

Comment: you can use Remix online ide to write contracts: https://remix.ethereum.org/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are trying to do, `return` is a reserved keyword you cannot use it for naming variables!

```
pragma solidity >=0.7.0 <0.9.0;

contract FinalExcercise {
    uint256 a = 300;
    uint256 b = 12;
    uint256 f = 47;

    function finalize() public view returns (uint256) {
        uint256 d = 23;
        if (a <= a && b < f) {
            return (d * 2) - b;
        }
    }
}
```